# Convert SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have from comodo:
- mydomain.key
- mydomain.pem
- private.key
- request.csr

Can somebody tell me howto convert it to .p12 file? My fw integrated web server only accepting p12 files.

If this is important this is wildcard SSL certificate *.mydomain

Many thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Ahh sorry Super User will be much better. Sorry for messing up. Answered already by comodo support. Have a nice day everyone

Comment: You might want to delete the question. Stack Overflow hunts in packs. Once you get 1 or 2 downvotes, some folks pour on the "me too" down votes that serve no real purpose (there is a purpose, but its not useful to the user).

Answer (score 0):

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey myDomain.key -in myDomain.crt